# Get the shown limits of the line in a matplotlib plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, event-handling

Say I have this simple matplotlib plot:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x_data = [0, 1.0]
y_data = [0, 1.0]
myline = ax.plot(x_data, y_data)

def on_keypress(event):
  if event.key == 'ctrl+p':
    print("Printing myline: {}".format(myline))

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', on_keypress)

plt.show()
```

Say, I run this, and I make a "Zoom to rectangle":

[image: plot image full]

... and thus, I get this zoomed region shown:

[image: plot image zoomed]

How can I find the coordinates of the endpoints of the shown segment of the line?

In the example code, a line is printed when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> - and when I hit that, I'd like the coordinates of the *shown* segment of the line to be printed, regardless of which segment is shown (if whole line is shown, then (0,0), (1,1) would be expected endpoints printed).

How can I do that? Of course, I'd like the method to work for an arbitrary line, not just the (0,0), (1,1) one ...

Comment: This is surprisingly non-trivial (at least for me) as I would not know where matplotlib stores the limits of objects in the viewing field. One could extract the view limits, then calculate the x-y pairs of the points defined by the view (xmin-y, xmax-y, x-ymin, x-ymax) plus the two original points x0-y0 and x1-y1 and then test which two (if any as you could also pan the view) of these six lie within the viewing field. However, this seems rather complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using shapely:

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString, box
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x_data = [0.7, 1.0]
y_data = [2.1, 3.4]
myline, = ax.plot(x_data, y_data)

def on_keypress(event):
  if event.key == 'ctrl+p':
    viewlim = ax.viewLim   
    linestr = LineString(myline.get_xydata())
    viewbox = box(viewlim.x0, viewlim.y0, viewlim.x1, viewlim.y1)    
    inters = viewbox.intersection(linestr)
    coords = np.asarray(inters.coords)
    print(coords)

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', on_keypress)

plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]

```
>>>[[0.79071429 2.49309524]
>>>[1.         3.4       ]]
```

Matplotlib must have something similar internally to calculate `clip on` parameters; however, I did not immediately find it in the source code.

Comment: Thank you, especially that it is confirmed that it is a difficult problem; I don't often stumble upon the need to get data like this, but when I do, I'm never sure if it is just something I failed to find in the docs - great to have this post as reference now!

Comment: I suggest un-accepting my answer - other people might have more insight than I have. Just because you and I did not find it in the source code does not mean nobody else will.

Comment: Thanks, @Mr.T - you are right, did the unaccept